# Nested observables / subscribe within observable

Tags: rxjs

Having read that you should never `subscribe` within another observable, I am having major difficulties understanding how to properly handle nested observables.

For every `Candidate` emitted, I want to match against multiple regular expressions, provided as an observable `getPatterns$()`. If one is found, it will be attached to the `Candidate` object.

```
 class Candidate {
    public name: string;
    public matchingRegularExpression: RegExp;
 }

 listOfCandidates = [new Candidate('one'), new Candidate('two')];

 private matchCandidates$(textToMatch: string): Observable<Candidate> {
    return from(this.listOfCandidates)
      .pipe(
        map(f => { 
          f.regExp = this.getRegExp(f); // sequential
          return f;
        }),
        map(cand: Candidate => {
           this.getPatterns$().subscribe(patterns => {
             if (....do some regexp matching...){
                cand.matchingRegularExpression = pattern;
             }
           });
        })
      )
```

I tried using `mergeMap` or `switchMap`, but those seem to be used when you want to merge 1 outer object with n inner ones. But my inner observable should simply extend my `Candidate` object and emit 2 values in this example.

Comment: So your `this.getPatterns$` doesn't depend on a candidate and returns the same value(s) for all candidates!? Also does `this.getPatterns$` emit only one value (array) or multiple ones over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, it's considered as a bad practice because you completely lose the reference of your second subscription, which could result in a leak if the source continue emitting.

Fortunately we have an operator called [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), it allows us to switch on a new observable, and thus, avoid subscribing inside the observer function.

> The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed. You can remember this by the phrase switch to a new observable.

edit: add snippet

```
class Candidate {
    public name: string;
    public matchingRegularExpression: RegExp;
 }

 listOfCandidates = [new Candidate('one'), new Candidate('two')];

private matchCandidates$(textToMatch: string): Observable<Candidate> {
    return from(this.listOfCandidates)
      .pipe(
        map(f => { 
          f.regExp = this.getRegExp(f); // sequential
          return f;
        }),
        switchMap(cand: Candidate => {
          return this.getPatterns$().pipe(
            map(patterns => {
              if (....do some regexp matching...){
                cand.matchingRegularExpression = pattern;
              }
              return cand
            })
          )})
         )
```

Comment: Note that this code will call `this.getPatterns$()` for every emitted candidate. So if the patterns to fetch are the same for all candidates you're performing unnecessary requests.